# Not having to re-define atributes in class inheritance in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I've got something like this:

```
Class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x

Class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, y):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.y = y

test = Child(y=42)
```

That works nice: test.y equals 42 and test.x equals None. The problem comes when I try to define x:

`test = Child(x=32, y=42)`

That obviously doesn't work; x argument wasn't expected. I know a fix for this would be:

```
Class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Child, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y
```

But I would need to do this for lots of variables in quite deep parent-child inheritance, and writing all previous arguments in every new `__init__` doesn't look pythonic, in my opinion. There's surely another way, but I don't know how.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use [`kwargs`](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/):

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        print 'got', x
        self.x = x

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, y, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y = y
```

The child automatically forwards it to the parent:

```
>> test = Child(y=42)
got None
>> test = Child(y=42, x=13)
got 13
```

---

This technically works, but I don't like it that much, though:

- The docstring of the subclass's ctor will not really explain what's expected. That's bad.
- If the number of arguments is small, the original question shouldn't be much of a problem. If the number is too large, perhaps the initialization parameters themselves need to form a class.

Comment: This is the "one obvious way to do it". If a cozy docstring in the leaf subclasses is important for the project, maybe creatiing a metaclass that will concatenate the docstrings of the classes and methods on the `mro` could be of use.

Comment: @jsbueno Using Python's ability to manipulate code's documentation is an interesting idea.